# ASP.NET: How to convert <A> or HtmlAnchor to static text?

Tags: asp.net, html

i have a repeater that will output a series of items:

```
<asp:repeater ... runat="Server">
   <itemtemplate>
      <a href="<%# GetItemLink(...) %>"><%# GetItemText %></a>
   <itemtemplate>
<asp:repeater>
```

But some items will not have an associated link, so i don't want them to be clickable. i tried making it a `runat=server` `HtmlAnchor`, and set the `htmlAnchor.Disabled = true` for the items are should not actually have a link - but they can still be clicked (it just makes the text gray)

i know how i'd do it in the olden days:

```
<% If IsLink Then %>
   <A href="<% =GetItemLink%">
<% End If %>
   <% =GetItemText %>
<% If IsLink Then %>
   </A>
<% End If %>
```

But that's the messy mixing code and html ASP way. What's the ASP.NET way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an  <asp:HyperLink > control, which displays the text normally if no link is supplied.

---

Edited to include example:

```
<asp:repeater ... runat="Server">
   <itemtemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink ... runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# GetItemLink(...) %>"> <%# GetItemText %></asp:HyperLink>
   <itemtemplate>
<asp:repeater>
```

In the above example, the anchor tag will be rendered to html regardless, but if the NavigateUrl attribute is an empty string, there will be no `href` at all and every browser I've ever used renders the text in a manner similar to spans (so look out for custom styles on <a >'s).